# NavigationBar button mis-alignment in some views on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I have a couple views that I'm showing as examples of a problem I'm having with buttons in the UINavigationBar.  Here is a view showing the button correctly:

[image]

Here is the button in another view mis-aligned:

[image]

In both views, I have a UINavigationBar, and within it, a button (which is an image).  In one view, the button displays aligned fine and fits in the navigation bar properly; however, when I use the back button (from the good view), the button on the navigation bar mis-aligns (seems like it's moving down, or zooming, or something).  I've scoured the code, and done lots of adjustments/tweaks in the storyboard for the view, but can't figure out why the button moves in the simulator.

I'm fairly new to iOS development, so I've turned on/off endlessly different settings in the storyboard, and nothing fixes it.

[image: Screenshot of the view hierarchy]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the nav bar's view hierarchy? You're using a custom `UIView` for the navigation item's `titleView`, but maybe the image that you put in it is bigger than the nav bar allows, or the image & label aren't constrained to the custom title view that they're in.

Comment: @NRitH  Thanks, I've added a screenshot that hopefully illustrates the UI a bit better

Comment: I also notice this only seems to be an issue on the iPhone 5 simulator.  Larger screens don't have this issue.  So I'm guessing it is an image size problem.